# docker setting command driven dynamic variable to use in run step

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'd like to see if there is a way to set a variable during a RUN step to call it later.

for example:

```
RUN test=$(lsb_release --release | awk '{print $2}') \
    touch /tmp/test.file && echo "$test" >> /tmp/test.file
```

My use case is that I want to download a package for the specific version of ubuntu the container is running.  While I could pass the version as an ARG at build time, i'd prefer docker build to discover it on its own; always trying to eliminate human input error whenever possible.

Maybe there is a better solution.

```
~$ docker build
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c   test=$(lsb_release --release | awk '{print $2}')     touch /tmp/test.file && echo \"$test\" >> /tmp/test.file" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was trying to use `\` to separate commands.

using a single RUN step worked as expected.

```
RUN test=$(lsb_release --release | awk '{print $2}') && touch /tmp/test.file && echo "$test" >> /tmp/test.file
```

checking

```
root@595715574cf8:/tmp# cat test.file
22.04
```

using multiple RUN steps failed

```
root@21d773376b17:/tmp# cat test.file

root@21d773376b17:/tmp#
```

on a side note, an alternative method instead of using `lsb_release`, is to set vars using `source /etc/os-release` and then calling the version with $VERISON_ID

ie.

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN source /etc/os-release && wget -c -P /tmp -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$VERSION_ID/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Comment: If you use the standard `.` shell built-in rather than the vendor-specific `source`, you don't need to change `SHELL`; `RUN . /etc/os-release && ...`